# Google cloud credentials for deploying cloud run service in CI pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am attempting to deploy a Cloud Run service from source from a GitLab CI pipeline. I can deploy it manually, with my own credentials, but am struggling to give the right credentials to the CI pipeline to get it to deploy.

These are the commands in my pipeline:

```bash
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $CLOUD_RUN_CREDENTIALS
gcloud run deploy api --source=./api/ --region=us-cental1
```

`CLOUD_RUN_CREDENTIALS` is a pipeline file variable that contains the key for a service account I have created for this purpose. The service account has the following roles:

- Cloud Build Editor role
- Artifact Registry Admin role
- Storage Admin role
- Cloud Run Admin role
- Service Account User role

In the Cloud Build settings I have enabled Cloud Run Admin and Service Account User.

When I run this GitLab job, I get the following error:

```
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $CLOUD_RUN_CREDENTIALS
Activated service account credentials for: [XXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
$ gcloud run deploy api --source=./api/ --region=us-cental1
ERROR: Error in retrieving repository from Artifact Registry.
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Is this a permissions issue? What permissions do I need to give this service account to allow the deployment to succeed? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It turns out that I misspelled "central"...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Build from Source feature. The Cloud Build Service Account is the one used to perform certain actions, like pulling and pushing images from Artifact Registry.

You have to grant the Cloud Build Service account (the one called PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com) the required permissions.

Go to IAM, look for the Cloud Build Service Account and grant it the permissions you listed above. That should solve the issue.

The Service Account used from GitLab doesn't need all these permissions. Cloud Run Admin should be enough

Comment: Thanks @boredabdel for the quick response! I added those permissions to the cloud build service account but am coming up with the same error.

Comment: Does work now after you have fixed the region name ?

Comment: Yup! Works great.